# Scrollbar move all columns in table, how to fix it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with data.
This table has fixed height, and 100% width.
When I have many rows - I need to show scrollbar. But this scrollbar move all my columns borders in a tbody. And I fixed this on Chrome (webkit). But on different devices, I'm not have this fix because overflow-y: overlay working only in (webkit) browsers. How can I fix this for all browsers?

[Screenshot in all browsers](http://joxi.ru/Vm67YXNHN9jZ2Z)

I have this styles:

```
  overflow-y: overlay;
  overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: please provide any demo or live site where you are getting issue.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/gacixedeju/edit?html,css,output but its very primitive

Comment: I can't say that, from the provided demo I am able to visually see the problem you are describing.